# Change to the date format 2021-03-18 09:30 in SAS

Tags: sas, format, date-format

I'd like to change the date format like the below. Just only excluding seconds... How should I do that. Please give me some advice.

```
data test;
 dt=1927221180;
 dt2=put(dt,NLDATM20.);
run;

* 2021/01/25 19:13:00 ;
* 2021-01-25 19:13      <----- I want it,   "/" -> "-" and no seconds
```

Comment: Roll your own format using a picture format or do the for the date and time separately. AFAIK there isn't a defined format for what you want but since you're converting to character it's not too important. I'm assuming you don't need to do any calculations or sorting of this data since it's a character?

Comment: Are you running on CAS? NLDATM isn't valid in Base....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either roll your own format or use a combination of formats as your date format is non-standard.

```
data test;
 dt=1927221180;
 dt2=catx(" ", 
          put(datepart(dt), yymmddd10.), 
          put(timepart(dt), hhmm5.));
          
 
run;
```

Note that character dates, such as dt2, cannot be used to calculate durations and they won't sort correctly, ie it will sort alphabetically.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a smart program, very useful, thank you.